# Detecting Regions Described by Lines on HTML5 Canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, geometry, jcanvas

Start with a 2d grid on an HTML5 canvas.  The user creates lines by plotting points - up to 5 lines.

Next, the user can select another arbitrary point on the grid, and the region is highlighted.  I need to take that point and define a polygon to fill the region described by the lines created by the user.

So my thought is, I need to detect the lines and canvas edges that surround the arbitrary point, and then draw a polygon.

Here is an image to help understand what I mean (where the system is functioning with two lines):

[image]

All the state is managed by using jCanvas and custom Javascript.

Thanks!

---

Wow... I just woke up and found these incredible answers.  Love SO.  Thanks guys.

Comment: So you want the point's region filled with color as opposed to needing a set of lines which form the region?  I ask because the first is a "simple" floodfill and the second is a math adventure ;-)

Comment: @markE - The simply floodfill :) - but how to detect the borders of the polygon and then use them to create the fill?

Comment: @markE I don't think there is a built in flood fill for canvas objects. There are some libraries and StackOverflow answers for this.

Comment: Ok, I've answered with an example that floodfills the region bounded by lines with a color.  Good luck with your project!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a complete working solution you can see it running at http://jsfiddle.net/SalixAlba/PhE26/2/
It uses pretty much the algorithm in my first answer.

```
// canvas and mousedown related variables
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
var $canvas = $("#canvas");
var canvasOffset = $canvas.offset();
var offsetX = canvasOffset.left;
var offsetY = canvasOffset.top;
var scrollX = $canvas.scrollLeft();
var scrollY = $canvas.scrollTop();

// save canvas size to vars b/ they're used often
var canvasWidth = canvas.width;
var canvasHeight = canvas.height;

// list of lines created
var lines = new Array();

// list of all solutions 
var allSolutions = new Array();
// solutions round bounding rect
var refinedSols = new Array();
// ordered solutions for polygon
var polySols = new Array();

/////////// The line type

// A line defined by  a x + b y + c = 0
function Line(a,b,c) {
    this.a = a;
    this.b = b;
    this.c = c;
}

// given two points create the line
function makeLine(x0,y0,x1,y1) {
    // Line is defined by 
    // (x - x0) * ( y1 - y0) = ( y - y0) * ( x1 - x0)
    // (y1-y0)*x - (x1-x0)* y + x0*(y1-y0)+y0*(x1-x0) = 0
    return new Line( (y1-y0), (x0-x1), -x0*(y1-y0)+y0*(x1-x0));
};

Line.prototype.toString = function () {
    var s = "" + this.a + " x ";
    s += (this.b >= 0 ? "+ "+this.b : "- "+ (-this.b) );
    s += " y ";
    s += (this.c >= 0 ? "+ "+this.c : "- "+ (-this.c) );
    return s + " = 0";
};

Line.prototype.draw = function() {
  var points = new Array();
  // find the intersecetions with the boinding box
    // lhs :  a * 0 + b * y + c = 0  
    if( this.b != 0 ) {
        var y = -this.c / this.b;
        if( y >= 0 && y <= canvasHeight ) 
            points.push([0,y]);
    }
    // rhs :  a * canvasWidth + b * y + c = 0  
    if( this.b != 0 ) {
        var y = ( - this.a * canvasWidth - this.c )/ this.b;
        if( y >= 0 && y <= canvasHeight ) 
            points.push([canvasWidth,y]);
    }
    // top : a * x + b * 0 + c = 0  
    if( this.a != 0 ) {
        var x = -this.c / this.a;
        if( x > 0 && x < canvasWidth ) 
            points.push([x,0]);
    }
    // bottom : a * x + b * canvasHeight + c = 0  
    if( this.a != 0 ) {
        var x = ( - this.b * canvasHeight - this.c )/ this.a;
        if( x > 0 && x < canvasWidth ) 
            points.push([x,canvasHeight]);
    }
    if(points.length == 2) {
      ctx.moveTo(points[0][0], points[0][1]);
      ctx.lineTo(points[1][0], points[1][1]);
    }
    else
      console.log(points.toString());
}

// Evalute the defining function for a line
Line.prototype.test = function(x,y) {
    return this.a * x + this.b * y + this.c;
}

// Find the intersection of two lines
Line.prototype.intersect = function(line2) {
    // need to solve
    // a1 x + b1 y + c1 = 0
    // a2 x + b2 y + c2 = 0
    var det = this.a * line2.b - this.b * line2.a;
    if(Math.abs(det) < 1e-6) return null;
    // (x) =  1  ( b2    -b1 ) ( -c1 )
    // ( ) = --- (           ) (     )
    // (y)   det ( -a2    a1 ) ( -c2 )
    var x = ( - line2.b * this.c + this.b * line2.c ) / det;
    var y = (   line2.a * this.c - this.a * line2.c ) / det;
    var sol = { x: x, y: y, line1: this, line2: line2 };
    return sol;
}

//// General methods 

// Find all the solutions of every pair of lines
function findAllIntersections() {
    allSolutions.splice(0); // empty
    for(var i=0;i<lines.length;++i) {
        for(var j=i+1;j<lines.length;++j) {
            var sol = lines[i].intersect(lines[j]);
            if(sol!=null)
                allSolutions.push(sol);
        }
    }
}

// refine solutions so we only have ones inside the feasible region
function filterSols(targetX,targetY) {
    refinedSols.splice(0);
    // get the sign on the test point for each line
    var signs = lines.map(function(line){
        return line.test(targetX,targetY);});
    for(var i=0;i<allSolutions.length;++i) {
        var sol = allSolutions[i];
        var flag = true;
        for(var j=0;j<lines.length;++j) {
            var l=lines[j];
            if(l==sol.line1 || l==sol.line2) continue;
            var s = l.test(sol.x,sol.y);
            if( (s * signs[j] ) < 0 )
                flag = false;
        }
        if(flag)
            refinedSols.push(sol);
    }
}

// build a polygon from the refined solutions
function buildPoly() {
    polySols.splice(0);
    var tempSols = refinedSols.map(function(x){return x});
    if(tempSols.length<3) return null;
    var curSol = tempSols.shift();
    var curLine = curSol.line1;
    polySols.push(curSol);
    while(tempSols.length>0) {
        var found=false;
        for(var i=0;i<tempSols.length;++i) {
            var sol=tempSols[i];
            if(sol.line1 == curLine) {
                curSol = sol;
                curLine = sol.line2;
                polySols.push(curSol);
                tempSols.splice(i,1); 
                found=true;
                break;
            }
            if(sol.line2 == curLine) {
                curSol = sol;
                curLine = sol.line1;
                polySols.push(curSol);
                tempSols.splice(i,1); 
                found=true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if(!found) break;
    }
}

// draw 
function draw() {
    console.log("drawlines");
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height)

    if(polySols.length>2) {
        ctx.fillStyle = "Orange";
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo(polySols[0].x,polySols[0].y);
        for(var i=1;i<polySols.length;++i)
            ctx.lineTo(polySols[i].x,polySols[i].y);
        ctx.closePath();
        ctx.fill();
    }

    ctx.lineWidth = 5;
    ctx.beginPath();
    lines.forEach(function(line, index, array) {console.log(line.toString()); line.draw();});

    ctx.fillStyle = "Blue";
    ctx.fillRect(x0-4,y0-4,8,8);
    ctx.fillRect(x1-4,y1-4,8,8);
    ctx.stroke();

    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.fillStyle = "Red";
    allSolutions.forEach(function(s,i,a){ctx.fillRect(s.x-5,s.y-5,10,10);});

    ctx.fillStyle = "Green";
    refinedSols.forEach(function(s,i,a){ctx.fillRect(s.x-5,s.y-5,10,10);});
    ctx.stroke();

}

var x0 = -10;
var y0 = -10;
var x1 = -10;
var y1 = -10;
var clickCount = 0; // hold the number of clicks

// Handle mouse clicks
function handleMouseDown(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    // get the mouse position
    var x = parseInt(e.clientX - offsetX);
    var y = parseInt(e.clientY - offsetY);

    if(clickCount++ % 2 == 0) {
        // store the position
        x0 = x;
        y0 = y;
        x1 = -10;
        y1 = -10;
        filterSols(x,y);
        buildPoly();
        draw();
    }
    else {
        x1 = x;
        y1 = y;
        var line = makeLine(x0,y0,x,y);
        lines.push(line);
        findAllIntersections();
        draw();
    }      
}

$("#canvas").mousedown(function (e) {
    handleMouseDown(e);
});


// add the lines for the bounding rectangle
lines.push(
    new Line( 1, 0, -50 ),  // first line is x - 50 >= 0
    new Line(-1, 0, 250 ),  // first line is  -x + 250 >= 0
    new Line( 0, 1, -50 ),  // first line is y - 50 >= 0
    new Line( 0,-1, 250 ) );  // first line is  -y + 250 >= 0

findAllIntersections();
draw();
```

Comment: Just playing and trying to brush up my javascript. Tip of the hat to @markE for the basic framework and showing me the jsfiddle way.

Comment: markE's way is good too, but I needed something more performant than floodfill turned out to be...

Comment: Your solution here is the feasible region one, am I right?

Comment: Yep using linear algebra. 1) Find all intersections, 2) Filter out points which don't satisfy inequalities 3) construct polygon by walking round remaining points and lines.

Comment: Can you help me unpack the `makeLine()` method - I am not groking the way the lines are represented there as a, b and c...

Answer (score 4):

**You can use flood filling to color clicked areas bounded by your user-defined lines.**

1. Let the user draw their lines on the canvas.
2. When the user clicks on a region bounded by lines, floodfill that region with a color.

Note: you must draw your gridlines underneath the canvas or else those gridlines will act as boundaries for the floodfill algorithm and you will just fill a grid cell.  You can use CSS to layer an image under your canvas or use a separate canvas to draw the gridlines.

[image]

Here's starting example code and a Demo:  http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/aY4Xs/

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="css/reset.css" /> <!-- reset css -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style>
    body{ background-color: ivory; }
    #canvas{border:1px solid red;}
</style>
<script>
$(function(){

    // canvas and mousedown related variables
    var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
    var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");
    var $canvas=$("#canvas");
    var canvasOffset=$canvas.offset();
    var offsetX=canvasOffset.left;
    var offsetY=canvasOffset.top;
    var scrollX=$canvas.scrollLeft();
    var scrollY=$canvas.scrollTop();

    // save canvas size to vars b/ they're used often
    var canvasWidth=canvas.width;
    var canvasHeight=canvas.height;

    // define the grid area
    // lines can extend beyond grid but
    // floodfill wont happen outside beyond the grid
    var gridRect={x:50,y:50,width:200,height:200}

    drawGridAndLines();

    // draw some test gridlines
    function drawGridAndLines(){
        ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height)
        // Important: the lineWidth must be at least 5
        // or the floodfill algorithm will "jump" over lines
        ctx.lineWidth=5;
        ctx.strokeRect(gridRect.x,gridRect.y,gridRect.width,gridRect.height);
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo(75,25);
        ctx.lineTo(175,275);
        ctx.moveTo(25,100);
        ctx.lineTo(275,175);
        ctx.stroke();
    }

    // save the original (unfilled) canvas
    // so we can reference where the black bounding lines are
    var strokeData = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, canvasWidth, canvasHeight);

    // fillData contains the floodfilled canvas data
    var fillData = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, canvasWidth, canvasHeight);


    // Thank you William Malone for this great floodFill algorithm!
    // http://www.williammalone.com/articles/html5-canvas-javascript-paint-bucket-tool/
    //////////////////////////////////////////////

    function floodFill(startX, startY, startR, startG, startB) {
      var newPos;
      var x;
      var y;
      var   pixelPos;
      var   neighborLeft;
      var   neighborRight;
      var   pixelStack = [[startX, startY]];

      while (pixelStack.length) {

        newPos = pixelStack.pop();
        x = newPos[0];
        y = newPos[1];

        // Get current pixel position
        pixelPos = (y * canvasWidth + x) * 4;

        // Go up as long as the color matches and are inside the canvas
        while (y >= 0 && matchStartColor(pixelPos, startR, startG, startB)) {
          y -= 1;
          pixelPos -= canvasWidth * 4;
        }

        pixelPos += canvasWidth * 4;
        y += 1;
        neighborLeft = false;
        neighborRight = false;

        // Go down as long as the color matches and in inside the canvas
        while (y <= (canvasHeight-1) && matchStartColor(pixelPos, startR, startG, startB)) {
          y += 1;

          fillData.data[pixelPos]     = fillColor.r;
          fillData.data[pixelPos + 1] = fillColor.g;
          fillData.data[pixelPos + 2] = fillColor.b;
          fillData.data[pixelPos + 3] = 255;


          if (x > 0) {
            if (matchStartColor(pixelPos - 4, startR, startG, startB)) {
              if (!neighborLeft) {
                // Add pixel to stack
                pixelStack.push([x - 1, y]);
                neighborLeft = true;
              }
            } else if (neighborLeft) {
              neighborLeft = false;
            }
          }

          if (x < (canvasWidth-1)) {
            if (matchStartColor(pixelPos + 4, startR, startG, startB)) {
              if (!neighborRight) {
                // Add pixel to stack
                pixelStack.push([x + 1, y]);
                neighborRight = true;
              }
            } else if (neighborRight) {
              neighborRight = false;
            }
          }

          pixelPos += canvasWidth * 4;
        }
      }
    }

    function matchStartColor(pixelPos, startR, startG, startB) {

      // get the color to be matched
      var r = strokeData.data[pixelPos],
        g = strokeData.data[pixelPos + 1],
        b = strokeData.data[pixelPos + 2],
        a = strokeData.data[pixelPos + 3];

      // If current pixel of the outline image is black-ish
      if (matchstrokeColor(r, g, b, a)) {
        return false;
      }

      // get the potential replacement color
      r = fillData.data[pixelPos];
      g = fillData.data[pixelPos + 1];
      b = fillData.data[pixelPos + 2];

      // If the current pixel matches the clicked color
      if (r === startR && g === startG && b === startB) {
        return true;
      }

      // If current pixel matches the new color
      if (r === fillColor.r && g === fillColor.g && b === fillColor.b) {
        return false;
      }

      return true;
    }

    function matchstrokeColor(r, g, b, a) {
      // never recolor the initial black divider strokes
      // must check for near black because of anti-aliasing
      return (r + g + b < 100 && a === 255);  
    }

    // Start a floodfill
    // 1. Get the color under the mouseclick
    // 2. Replace all of that color with the new color
    // 3. But respect bounding areas! Replace only contiguous color.
    function paintAt(startX, startY) {

      // get the clicked pixel's [r,g,b,a] color data
      var pixelPos = (startY * canvasWidth + startX) * 4,
        r = fillData.data[pixelPos],
        g = fillData.data[pixelPos + 1],
        b = fillData.data[pixelPos + 2],
        a = fillData.data[pixelPos + 3];

      // this pixel's already filled
      if (r === fillColor.r && g === fillColor.g && b === fillColor.b) {
        return;
      }

      // this pixel is part of the original black image--don't fill
      if (matchstrokeColor(r, g, b, a)) {
        return;
      }

      // execute the floodfill
      floodFill(startX, startY, r, g, b);

      // put the colorized data back on the canvas
      ctx.putImageData(fillData, 0, 0);
    }

    // end floodFill algorithm
    //////////////////////////////////////////////


    // get the pixel colors under x,y
    function getColors(x,y){
        var data=ctx.getImageData(x,y,1,1).data;
        return({r:data[0], g:data[1], b:data[2], a:data[3] });
    }

    // create a random color object {red,green,blue}
    function randomColorRGB(){
        var hex=Math.floor(Math.random()*16777215).toString(16);
        var r=parseInt(hex.substring(0,2),16);
        var g=parseInt(hex.substring(2,4),16);
        var b=parseInt(hex.substring(4,6),16);
        return({r:r,g:g,b:b});    
    }

    function handleMouseDown(e){
      e.preventDefault();

      // get the mouse position
      x=parseInt(e.clientX-offsetX);
      y=parseInt(e.clientY-offsetY);

      // don't floodfill outside the gridRect
      if(
          x<gridRect.x+5 || 
          x>gridRect.x+gridRect.width ||
          y<gridRect.y+5 ||
          y>gridRect.y+gridRect.height
      ){return;}

      // get the pixel color under the mouse
      var px=getColors(x,y);

      // get a random color to fill the region with
      fillColor=randomColorRGB();

      // floodfill the region bounded by black lines
      paintAt(x,y,px.r,px.g,px.b);
    }

    $("#canvas").mousedown(function(e){handleMouseDown(e);});

}); // end $(function(){});
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <h4>Click in a region within the grid square.</h4>
    <canvas id="canvas" width=300 height=300></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

**[ Info about getImageData and the pixel array ]**

`context.getImageData().data` gets an array representing r,g,b & a values of the specified area of the canvas (in our case we selected the whole canvas).  The top-left pixel (0,0) is the first element(s) in the array.

Each pixel is represented by 4 sequential elements in the array.

The first array element holds the red component (0-255), the next element holds blue, the next holds green and the next holds the alpha (opacity).

```
// pixel 0,0
red00=data[0];
green00=data[1];
blue00=data[2];
alpha00=data[3];

// pixel 1,0
red10=data[4];
green10=data[5];
blue10=data[6];
alpha10=data[7];
```

Therefore, you jump to the red element of any pixel under the mouse like this:

```
// pixelPos is the position in the array of the first of 4 elements for pixel (mouseX,mouseY)

var pixelPos = (mouseY * canvasWidth + mouseX) * 4
```

And you can get all 4 r,g,b,a values by getting the next 4 pixel array elements

```
var r = fillData.data[pixelPos];
var g = fillData.data[pixelPos + 1];
var b = fillData.data[pixelPos + 2];
var a = fillData.data[pixelPos + 3];
```

Comment: thanks!  I'm a bit confused by the fillData section at the beginning of paintAt() (lines 168-172).  What does the math at 168 get you, and how does the getImageDate() call that populates the fillData var get you the RGBA values?

Comment: You're welcome!  The `fillData` array holds the pixels as they are currently colored.  pixelPos=(mouseY*canvasWidth+mouseX)*4 goes into that array at the clicked mouse position and gets the color of the pixel under the mouse.  Then the floodfill algorithm looks for all neighboring pixels of that same color and changes them to a new color.  I've added to my answer to explain how getImageData works to get the color value of pixels.  :-)

Comment: That is an *awesome* explanation of how getImageData works - thanks.

Comment: @markE: Your code works well with thick strokes. But when lineWidth is set to 1, the floodfill will fill the entire square. What adjustment would matchstrokeColor() need to work in such a situation?

Answer (score 1):

Your first step is to find the two lines. There are various way of describing the lines: the traditional `y=m x + c`, a implicit form `a x+b y+c=0`, a parametric form `(x,y) = (x0,y0) + t(dx,dy)`. Probably the most useful is the implicit form, as this can describe vertical lines.

If you have two points (x1,y1) and (x2,y2) the line can be given as `y=y1 + (x-x1) (y2-y1)/(x2-x1)`. or `(y-y1) * (x2-x1) = (x-x1)*(y2-y1)`.

You can do this for the two lines defined by the four points.

To actually draw the regions you will need to find the point where the lines intersect, this is standard solving two linear equation problem, which you probably did at high school. You will also need to find the points where the lines cross the boundary of your region. This is easier to find as you can just put the x or y values for the boundary into the equations and find the other coordinate. You probably also need to add a point at the corner of the box.

There will need to be some logic to work out which of the four possible segments you want.

For multiple lines you could treat it as a set of inequalities. You need to work out the equations of the lines say `a1 * x + b1 * y + c1 >= 0`, `a2 * x + b2 * y + c2 <= 0` ... Call these E1, E2, ... The inequality will depend on which side of the line you want to be on. (Its not clear from the original question how your going to work this out.)

The simplest method uses a pixel based technique. Loop through the pixels in an image and set the pixel if all the inequalities are satisfied.

```
var myImageData = context.createImageData(width, height);
for(var x=xmin;i<xmax;++i) {
  for(var y=ymin;j<ymax;++j) {
    if( (a1 * x + b1 * y + c1 >= 0 ) &&
        (a2 * x + b2 * y + c2 >= 0 ) &&
        ...
        (a9 * x + b9 * y + c9 >= 0 ) ) 
    {
      var index = ((y-ymin)*width + (x-xmin))*4; // index of first byte of pixel
      myImageData.data[index] = redValInside;
      myImageData.data[index+1] = greenValInside;
      myImageData.data[index+2] = blueValInside;
      myImageData.data[index+3] = alphaValInside;
   } else {
      var index = ((y-ymin)*width + (x-xmin))*4; // index of first byte of pixel
      myImageData.data[index] = redValOutside;
      myImageData.data[index+1] = greenValOutside;
      myImageData.data[index+2] = blueValOutside;
      myImageData.data[index+3] = alphaValOutside;
   }
 }
```

}

If you want to actually get a polygon that becomes quite hard. You want to find the [Feasible region](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feasible_region) defined by your inequalities. This is a classic problem in [Linear_programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_programming) their might be a library out there which solves this.

A sketch algorithm for this might be. Assume lines are in form 'a x + b y + c >= 0'

```
// find all solutions for intersections of the lines
var posibleSols = new Array();
for(var line1 : all lines) {
  for(var line2 : all lines) {
    var point = point of intersection of line1 and line2
    point.lineA = line1;  // store the two lines for later use
    point.lineB = line2;  
  }
}

// refine solutions so we only have ones inside the feasible region
var refinedSols = new Array();
for(var i=0;i<posibleSols.length;++i) {
  var soln = possibleSols[i];
  var flag = true; // flag to tell if the line passes
  for(var line : all lines) {
    if( line == soln.line1 || line == soln.line2 ) continue;  // don't test on lines for this point
    if( line.a * point.x + line.b * point.b + line.c < 0 ) {
      flag = false; // failed the test
    }
  }
  if(flag) 
    refinedSols.push(sol); // if it passed all tests add it to the solutions
}

// final step is to go through the refinedSols and find the vertices in order
var result = new Array();
var currentSol = refinedSols[0];
result.push(currentSol);
var currentLine = startingSol.lineA;
refinedSols.splice(0,1); // remove soln from array
while(refinedSols.length>0) {
  // fine a solution on the other end of currentLine
  var nextSol;
  for(var i=0;i< refinedSols.length;++i) {
    nextSol = refinedSols[i];
    if(nextSol.lineA == currentLine ) {
      currentSol = nextSol;
      currentLine = nextSol.lineA;
      result.push(currentSol);
      refinedSols.splice(i,1); // remove this from list
      break;
    }
    else if( nextSol.lineB == currentLine ) {
      currentSol = nextSol;
      currentLine = nextSol.lineB;
      result.push(currentSol);
      refinedSols.splice(i,1); // remove this from list
      break;
    }
  }
  // done you can now make a polygon from the points in result
```